# White Color to RGB not correct

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Check out the code

```
const CGFloat *c = CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]); 
slider1.value = c[0];
slider2.value = c[1];
slider3.value = c[2];
```

c[2] is getting 0. For whiteColor all RGB values shld be 1.0. Why its not returning correct value for the blue component?

Any code snippet? for getting RGB values from white color?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `CGColorGetColorSpace([[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor])`

You will see it is not RGB. It has 2 components only: greyscale and alpha

Comment: The color space used for white is grayscale (1 component and alpha). To get RGB values from grayscale color, you have to use the grayscale value for R, G and B.

Comment: slider1.value = c[0]; slider2.value = c[0]; slider3.value = c[0];

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx,[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

Works with colors and grayscale.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet of code should work with both RGB and grayscale:

```
CGFloat *components = (CGFloat *) CGColorGetComponents(<UIColor instance>.CGColor);
if(CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(<UIColor instance>.CGColor) == 2)
{
  //assuming it is grayscale - copy the first value
  components[2] = components[1] = components[0];
}
```